Laravel - How to use Mockery to mock service bindings?
I have the following class:
class Testclass
{
    public WebshopappApiClient $client;

    public function __construct(Webshop $webshop)
    {
        $this->client = app()->make(WebshopappApiClient::class, ['webshop' => $webshop]);
    }

    public function callTestMethod()
    {
        // This should be Mock value std empty class
        dd($this->client->shipments);
    }
}

with the following service provider:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Webshop;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WebshopappApiClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\WebshopappApiClient::class, function ($app, $params): \WebshopappApiClient {
            /** @var Webshop $webshop */
            $webshop = $params['webshop'];

            $key = $webshop->key;
            $value = $webshop->value;

            return new \WebshopappApiClient($key, $value);
        });
    }
}


I want to use Mockery to override the call to $this->client->shipments in Testclass in my tests:
public function testShipWithTracking(): void
{
    $mockClient = Mockery::mock(\WebshopappApiClient::class);
    $mockClient->shipments = Mockery::mock('stdClass');
    app()->instance(\WebshopappApiClient::class, $mockClient);

    $webshop = new Webshop([
         'key' => 'test',
         'value' => 'test',
    ]);
    $testClass = new Testclass($webshop);
    // Still returns the real object instead of the mocked std class?
    $testClass->callTestMethod();
}

It seems like the mocking doesn't actually work. The dd($this->client->shipments) still returns the original object instead of an empty std class. How can I make sure that this service binding is overwritten with the mock object without altering the constructor of the class?
The underlying goal is to mock all API responses from this api client class without altering the constructor of the Testclass. This class is called dozens of times throughout legacy code.

The answer to this question is that only Facade implementations can be overridden with the app()->inject(...) call. This is a concrete implementation which should really be injected directly with a mock object
